# Running UiAutomator tests without Android Studio run option

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-uiautomator

I have built some tests on Android Studio using Uiautomator, but I dont want to run them on Android Studio (could be .jar file or .apk that can be run in any android device). The problem is those tests will not run in a user app, but in Android OS (example: performing a call to 123456 and ending the call)

How can I do it? The apk it generates doesnt work (force close) and it seems Android doesnt run .jar files (I need a NO ROOT solution.. can some1 help ke out? This have been killing me for long time.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have built some tests on Android Studio using Uiautomator, but I dont want to run them on Android Studio

All instrumentation tests, including UiAutomator tests, must be run from a development machine. You do not have to use Android Studio — for example, you can run instrumentation tests from the command line with Gradle. But they have to be run from a development machine.

Comment: @AndréRamos: Read the [building and running from the command line documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) and the [Android Plugin for Gradle documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html) for the basics of doing command-line work. You can [run the `connectedAndroidTask` task to run your instrumentation tests](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#run-instrumented-tests).

Comment: Good. I've solved my problem using command line approach (gradlew cAT). I just want to know exactly what should I have installed to run this command (sdk or Android studio), because I want to run these tests from other PCS with less development confguration possible.. Thanks

Comment: @AndréRamos: Gradle and the Android SDK. Android Studio is not required.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the test APK

```
$ ./gradlew assembleAndroidTest
```

Then you can install the APK on a device and run the tests using `adb`

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.example.app.MyTest com.example.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

so you will only need `adb` on the machine used to run the tests, which if  it's Ubuntu/Debian you can install just by

```
$ sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```